# Integration doubt in notation.

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I come across two notations while solving integrals : 
 $1.\int_a^bf(x)dx$
$2.\int_{[a,b]}f(x)dx$.
For improper integrals,
$1.\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$
$2.\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx$
 Is there any difference, espectially for the improper integral case ? 
 I'm confused because we have the following identity :
 $\int_a^bf(x)dx=-\int_b^af(x)dx$
 But, in the other notation, there seems to be no differences between $[a,b]$ and $[b,a]$ ?

Answer (score 1):

No. The first notation is more common for integrals over intervals, but the second type of notation is more convenient for more general domains (for example a complicated domain in $\mathbb R ^2$).